# Why can't I extract all filenames correctly when I traverse the dentry of a directory in a kernel module in the android kernel?

Tags: android, c, linux, file-io, linux-kernel

For an antirootkit student project, I want to get a list of filenames of a given directory in a kernel module. I know file IO is usually a bad idea in kernel space but this is a special case.

I used `filp_open` to get a `struct file` of the directory. With this I have a `struct dentry` which has the list `d_subdirs` which should consist of all files in the given directory.

When I traverse the list and printk all `d_iname` of the `struct dentry` which should be the short name of the `struct dentry`, there are non-ASCII symbols and some files in the directory are missing. There is no rootkit running which could hide those. The dmesg output looks like this:

```
<6>Filename: �đ�@�Y�android_module17.ko 
<6>Filename: <��� 
<6>Filename: <� 
<6>Filename: <��� 
<6>Filename: <����Ë�android_module15.ko 
<6>Filename: <��؀ŋ�android_module14.ko 
<6>Filename: <���@ǋ�android_module13.ko 
<6>Filename: <��� 
<6>Filename: <����ʋ�k 
<6>Filename: <��؀̋�android_module11.ko 
<6>Filename: <���@΋�android_module10.ko 
<6>Filename: <���@���android_module9.ko 
<6>Filename: <��� 
<6>Filename: <�����android_module7.ko 
<6>Filename: <Ê؀���android_module6.ko 
<6>Filename: <Ċ�@���android_module5.ko 
<6>Filename: <Ŋ� 
<6>Filename: <Ɗ�����10-__rttest 
<6>Filename: <Ǌ؀���__rttest 
<6>Filename: <Ȋ�@���proctest.ko 
<6>Filename: <ʊ� 
<6>Filename: <ˊ�����rt.ko 
<6>Filename: <̊؀���android_module4.ko 
<6>Filename: <͊�@���anmo.ko 
<6>Filename: <��� 
<6>Filename: ������Z�LOST.DIR 
<6>Filename: �҉�@�Z�Android
```

There is for example the folder DCIM which is missing or a file called android_module1.ko. I don't see anything special with these files.

This is the code of my kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/namei.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h> 

//replace the "" with angular brackets
int init_module(void)
{
    struct file * fi;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello android kernel...\n");

    fi = filp_open("/sdcard/", O_RDONLY, 0);

    //struct path testpath = fi->f_path;
    struct dentry * thedentry;
    thedentry = fi->f_dentry;
    struct dentry * curdentry;

    unsigned char * curname = NULL;

    list_for_each_entry(curdentry, &thedentry->d_subdirs, d_subdirs) {
        curname = curdentry->d_iname;

        printk(KERN_INFO "Filename: %s \n", curname);
    }
    filp_close(fi, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye android kernel...\n");

}
```

When I try to access the inodes when traversing the list, android crashes.  Can I somehow list all the files this way?

Edit:

Interestingly, If I try to manually correct the curdentry pointer like this in the loop:

```
testchar = (char *)curdentry;
testchar = testchar + 8;

curdentry = (struct dentry *)testchar;
curname = curdentry->d_iname;

testchar = (char *)curdentry;
testchar = testchar - 8;

curdentry = (struct dentry *)testchar;
```

Wow, this looks ugly, but with this the random symbols are gone. I just do not see where this pointer mismatch comes from. Am I using the list functions correctly?

Comment: Does this compile cleanly, with all warnings on (`-Wall`)?

Comment: @alk only warning is ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations of code.

Comment: WAG: The structure pointer `fi->f_dentry` points to a `struct dentry` that is somehow different from this code's understanding of `struct dentry`.  The garbage text in front of good filenames looks like `curname` points to maybe 8 addresses too low so it prints the contents of fields `d_bucket` and maybe `d_hash` before getting to `d_iname`.  Maybe kernel code and this code have differing pointer size?

Comment: @chux I tried to manually adjust the pointer and it worked. So it must be some kind of pointer issue like you suggested. I think the kernel and this module were built using the same compiler. How would I check the pointer sizes of the kernel and the kernel module?

Comment: Not familiar enough with android to advise further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong field that contains name: `d_iname` is just a buffer to save allocations that could be not used for large filenames. Actually you seek for `d_name.name`.

Also you incorrectly traverse list (I wonder how you get any results from it). `d_subdirs` is a *head* of list and used as 2nd argument in `list_for_each_entry()`, but in third argument you should put *node*, not *head* which in case of `d_entry` is `d_child` field (`d_u.d_child` in older kernels).

Here are your code after some polishing:

```
struct file * fi;
struct dentry * thedentry;
struct dentry * curdentry;
const char * curname = NULL;

printk(KERN_INFO "Hello android kernel...\n");

fi = filp_open("/root/", O_RDONLY, 0);
thedentry = fi->f_dentry;

list_for_each_entry(curdentry, &thedentry->d_subdirs, d_u.d_child) {
    curname = curdentry->d_name.name;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Filename: %s \n", curname);
}

filp_close(fi, NULL);
```

I checked it on vanilla Linux 3.12.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just to be clear, d_subdirs is the head of the list and d_u.d_child is the member which points to the next dentry. How do I know that two `struct list_head` are connected in the linux kernel?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no mechanism to do that. I found that `d_u.d_child` is a "node" in kernel sources, so you may try read comments or search for a corresponding `list_add_tail()` or `list_add()`